# MySQL: Count() Subquery returns nothing

Tags: mysql, select, count

I want to count all user id's and all entries in the table country. But when I execute my query it doesn't display any result.

```
SELECT (
  SELECT
    COUNT(userId)
  FROM
    tbl_user
)
AS
  countUser,
(
  SELECT
    country
  FROM
    tbl_user
)
AS
  country
```

I appreciate every help and comment!

Comment: What exactly is your expected output? The number of `userId`s per country? Also, your `... in the table country` makes no sense as your query uses no such table.

Comment: I get all counts of the userID but just one country. The thing is, that I've more then just one country

Comment: I get that, but you would you like this data to be presented? Do you need the total count of `userId`s for every row? That doesn't make much sense.

Comment: No I don't that is the problem right know with @Andrews B Anthony solution. I need the count of userID just one time (one row) and then as a secound "table" the countrys

Comment: To get two different resultsets, you need to make two separate queries. If you need to present the resultsets together you have to combine them later programmatically.

Comment: thanks for helping me too btw @Antti29 - So do I've to join them then? Do you have maybe an example for my task?

Comment: If you mean an SQL join, that's a totally different thing. It seems to me you don't yet have a very good grasp of what can and can't be done with database queries, so you should probably study that a bit. For this specific problem, two queries are needed, which then must be combined they way you want them with the programming language of your choice (which is beyond the scope of this question).

Answer (score 0):

Use the below query

```
select (select count(userId) from tbl_user) as userCount , 
userId, country from tbl_user
```

Comment: are you not missing group by clause?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried this too but then I just get one result. For instance I've 12 countrys but because of my count() I just get one country. I want one table (userCount) who really just count all entries for example: 30 user id's. And the other table should display all entries from the table country

Comment: changed the query @This.Sven

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```
select * from (
     select count(id) as countUser, name as country from tbl_user
) b
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this solution does output just one country too.

Comment: can you explain your schema, so it can helpful to understand what you want in output